# Invoke a method which is inside @configuration class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have a class as below:

```
@Configuration
Public class myConfig implements InitilizingBean{

Private List<HashMap<String,String>> mqConfigsfromDB = null;

...
...

public void reload(){
  initialize();
}
public void initialize(){
  //Load values from Db
  //set to the values to List 
  //mqConfigsfromDB
}

Public void afterPropertiesSet(){
  initialize();
}
}
```

**I want to call the reload() method from a different class.**

This config class loads mq configaration from DB and sets the listeners which is working fine. I just want to have a trigger point to reload the config from another class via the reload() method.

Any thoughts on how do I achieve the same?

Comment: when you ask a question, then you reviews the answer and accept the answer which resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can @Autowire in @Configuration annotated classes.

PS: There is an @PostConstruct annotation you can use to do the initializing instead of having to called .initialize().

Comment: Using `@Autowired` on `@Configuration` annotated class should be suggested and also not rightful.  `@PostConstruct` was a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

`@Configuration` annotation is used to create the bean and load other configurations. Calling method of such does not comes under best practices.
For your scenario, you can replace the `@Configuration` annotation with `@Component` and use `@PostConstruct` annotation on `initialize` method to automatically load configuration first time.

```
@Component
Public class LoadMQProperties {

Private List<HashMap<String,String>> mqConfigsfromDB = null;

public void reload(){
  initialize();
}

@PostConstruct
public void initialize(){
  //Load values from Db
  //set to the values to List 
  //mqConfigsfromDB
}

}
```